# Typescript regex

Tags: regex, typescript

I want to make typescript validation to this: 01-23-456789

I have one for account number :

```
this.contractForm.controls.account.get('accNum').setValue(val.match(/[0-9]{1,8}/g)?.join('-'))
```

This is easy because the account numbers look like this :

```
12345678-12345678-12345678
```

And I'm not a regex expert unfortunately, and I don't know how to make for this, that I mentioned in my first sentence.

```
 public businessNumberValidator() {
    return this.contractForm.controls.szerzodo
      .get('businessnum')
      .valueChanges.pipe(
        throttleTime(1),
        tap((val: string) => {
          const char = val.replace(/\D/g, '').split('');
          if (char.length > 2) {
            char.splice(2, 0, '-');
          }
          if (char.length > 5) {
            char.splice(5, 0, '-');
          }

          this.contractForm.controls.szerzodo.get('businessnum').setValue(char.join(''));
        }),
        untilDestroyed(this)
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

and I write this kind of solution, but I want a better one

Comment: Like this? `^\d+(?:-\d+)+$` https://regex101.com/r/greKgy/1

Comment: i don't need the '-' , because i will join the '-', as you see in the example

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: not string number, when i start write this 4444123456, i want to autocomplete the '-', and look like this 44-44-123456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
val.replace(/\D+/g,'')
  .replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,6})?$/, (_,x,y,z) => 
    z ? `${x}-${y}-${z}` : y ? `${x}-${y}` : x)
```

Here,

- `.replace(/\D+/g,'')` - removes all non-digit chars from string
- `^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,6})?$` - matches 1 or 2 first digits into Group 1 (`x` variable), next one or two digits are captured into an optional Group 2 (`y` variable), and then one to six digits are captured into an optional Group 3 (`z` variable); then if Group 3 matched, the replacement is `Group1-Group2-Group3`, if Group 2 matched, the replacement is `Group1-Group2`, else, the replacement is just Group 1  value.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
function m (val) {
  const char = val.replace(/\D/g, '').split('');
          if (char.length > 2) {
            char.splice(2, 0, '-');
          }
          if (char.length > 5) {
            char.splice(5, 0, '-');
          }
  return char.join("");
}
function m2 (val) {
  return val.replace(/\D+/g,'')
    .replace(/^(\d{1,2})(\d{1,2})?(\d{1,6})?$/, (_,x,y,z) => 
      z ? `${x}-${y}-${z}` : y ? `${x}-${y}` : x)
}
const val = "01-23-456789";

document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>=== Current approach: ===</br>"
for (let i=1; i<=val.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += m(val.substring(0,i)) + "<br/>";
}
document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>=== New regex approach: ===</br>"
for (let i=1; i<=val.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += m2(val.substring(0,i)) + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very muck dude! It worked!
And also great explanation!

Answer (score -1):

Use this pattern:

`\d{2,6}`

[See Demo](https://regex101.com/r/EFiBwR/2)